# How to show two data series are out-of-phase

Tags: time-series

[image]

I have two time series as shown below. Now I need to show that they are out-of-phase. The data here is ice volume in Antarctica (Red) and Greenland (Blue). I need to show that the glacial cycles are anti-phased, i.e. when Red is at peak, blue is at a trough. But the catch is they may not be exactly aligned.

What is the best way to show the out-of-phase behaviour?

Comment: If they are "not exactly aligned," then what does "out of phase" actually mean?  For instance, perhaps the misalignment is one-half of a cycle: then the peaks line up and the troughs line up, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to to determine the phase or more precisely the lagged relationship between the two series. The method of choice is called  a Transfer Function also known as a Dynamic Regression while being sensitive to anomalous behavior such as Pulses , Level Shifts , Seasonal Pulses , Local Time Trends . Care should also be taken to incorporate time varying parameters and time varying error variance if necessary. If you post your data (excel file preferred), I will (naturally) demonstrate this.